# jQuery AJAX Load Content Problem

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a XHTML Strict Website 'main.php' with a normal Header where jQuery and other Scripts are loaded - also there's a menu:

```
        <div id="tab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="content('load/feed.php');"><img src="feed_active.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Feed" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="content('load/feed2.php');"><img src="feed2_off.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Feed2" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

On Click the URL is loaded via jQuery.load(); into the #content div. Everything works fine and also the CSS defined in the main.php for the feed.php is added to
the #content div.

Now the Problem: in the loaded File e.g. feed.php there's an Image

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

i have added my own jQuery.mouseover, mouseout function - and it does not work! Also i have a  input Box in the main.php
and in the feed.php which is loaded via AJAX there's a link e.g.

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#entermessage').val('test');">
```

It does also not work, why? I thought the AJAX loaded page is **integrated** to the main.php? But all my JS/jQuery Stuff does not work?

Hope you understand and hope you can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) event handlers:

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element. Can also bind custom
>   events.

Such as:

```
$('#myImage').live("mouseover", function() {
    // do stuff
}).live("mouseout", function() {
    // do stuff
});

$('#myLink').live("click", function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Not to mention the importance of keeping logic out of your presentation :)